# How to build a two-layer-deep GRU autoencoder with the keras.Model API?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder

this is my attempt at building a two-layer autoencoder with keras:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

time_steps = 2000
latent_space_dim_1 = 100
latent_space_dim_2 = 40
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(time_steps, 1))

x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_2, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = layers.RepeatVector(time_steps)(x)
x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_2, return_sequences=True)(x),
x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True)(x),
model = keras.Model(inputs, x)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipvalue=0.01), loss="mse")
model.summary()
```

On execution this error is returned:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\FRANK~1.PAE\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14412/3102426595.py in 
      8 x = layers.RepeatVector(time_steps)(x)
      9 x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_2, return_sequences=True)(x),
---> 10 x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True)(x),
     11 model = keras.Model(inputs, x)
     12 model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipvalue=0.01), loss="mse")

TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '(None, 40)' with type ''
```

What am I doing wrong here?

For the Sequential API the following code is executable:

```py
latent_space_dim_1 = 128
latent_space_dim_2 = 32
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(time_steps, 1)),
        layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True),
        layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_2, return_sequences=False),
        layers.RepeatVector(time_steps),
        layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_2, return_sequences=True),
        layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True),
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipvalue=0.01), loss="mse")
model.summary()
```

Also, an autoencoder with just one layer runs nicely:

```py
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(time_steps, 1))

x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=False)(inputs)
x = layers.RepeatVector(time_steps)(x)
x = layers.GRU(latent_space_dim_1, return_sequences=True)(x),
model = keras.Model(inputs, x)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipvalue=0.01), loss="mse")
model.summary()
```

Remark:
I want to use the Model API (instead of Sequential) to make the preprocessing part of the model instead of the input pipeline (the preprocessing layers are ommitted in the code supplied above for the sake of clarity) as described in this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers)

Comment: Remove the commas at the end of each line in the functional definition, this is what produces the problem